# Writing to a Perl Process Input Stream in Java

Tags: java, perl, http, unix, web-applications

I am trying to program a simple webserver class using java that runs on UNIX.

The WebServer class will call a perl script that will generate the HTML based on the requests.

Consider this:

1. Client sends HTTP POST Request to the WebServer
2. Read HTTP POST Body : `"description=asd&action=add"`
3. HTTP POST Body written to a `byte[] byteParams` seen below
4. Need to write `byteParams` to the Perl Process object for it to generate appropriate HTML

Code:

```
String postParams = "/usr/bin/env REQUEST_METHOD=POST QUERY_STRING= " +" CONTENT_LENGTH=" + contentLength + " CONTENT_TYPE=" + contentType + " /usr/bin/perl " + filename;
Process perlProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(postParams);

DataOutputStream writeToPerl = new DataOutputStream(perlProcess.getOutputStream());             
//write the http post request body to writeToPerl    
writeToPerl.write(byteParams, 0, byteParams.length);            

InputStreamReader readFromPerlInputStream = new InputStreamReader(perlProcess.getInputStream());
BufferedReader readFromPerl = new BufferedReader(readFromPerlInputStream);    
BufferedReader readFromPerlError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(perlProcess.getErrorStream()));
```

So now we have the perlProcess object that will read the Environment Variables in UNIX to generate the appropriate HTML.

After writing to the DataOutputStream of the Perl Process object, will it automatically write to its standard output based on the input (the HTTP Post body)?

Or do I need to tell the Process object to read what I just wrote to the `DataOutputStream writeToPerl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

After writing to the `DataOutputStream` of the Perl Process object, it will automatically write to its standard output (`BufferedReader readFromPerl`), based on the inputs in the `DataOutputStream`.

I had some file permission issue causing me to ask this question as I did not get the expected outfrom from the `BufferedReader` of the Perl object after writing into its `DataOutputStream`